# How to configure elastic stack docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, filebeat

I've started using elastic docker.But I need to configure it for myself, for example, I want the contents of the /var/log/.* files in my system.I don't want nginx and apache logs. How can I achieve this?

https://github.com/elastic/examples/tree/master/Miscellaneous/docker/full_stack_example

Is there anyone who can help solve the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Default location of ES logs is :  /var/log/elasticsearch

So, you can create a volume in docker-compose file :

```
volumes :
    - /folder/in/your/pc:/var/log/elasticsearch
```

Comment: how can I achieve this, can you give details

Comment: In docker-compose-xxx.yml (xxx depends on your os), under volumes in "elasticsearch", add - /folder/in/your/pc:/var/log/elasticsearch)

Comment: for example, in the filebeat container in the docker-compose-linux.yml file - /var/log/.*:/var/log/elasticsearch
in this way?

Comment: No, first part of volumes (before :) must be a real folder in your pc (like /home/lisa/elasticsearch_logs:/var/log/elasticsearch for example)

Comment: unfortunately cannot understand

Comment: I think, you must read the documentation to understand : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: I just don't understand, /var/log/.* How do I read the contents of this file?

Comment: /var/log/.* is not an unique file... it's return all folders starts with . in /var/log

Comment: Can you give me an example from the compose file on github?